# Can wife disobey husband's illegal/adharmic orders?

Tags: mahabharata, marriage, smriti

Pranam
Suppose a perverted or a mentally unsound husband orders a wife to go someone else(to be with him(have sexual relation with him)) then I think it is adharmic..
My question is can wife disobey?
Is there any scriptural passage that forbids wife from following husband's illegal orders?
No general answers please.
Kindly mention scriptural references..
Thanks..

Comment: Also, for serious cases you should follow the law accepted by people[manu 4.175-176]

Answer (score 1):

Manusmriti 9.46

> न निष्क्रयविसर्गाभ्यां भर्तुर्भार्या विमुच्यते ।
>
> एवं धर्मं विजानीमः प्राक् प्रजापतिनिर्मितम् ॥ ४६ ॥
>
> Either by sale or by repudiation the wife is not released from her
> husband; such is the law that we know, as originally propounded by
> prajapati.— (46)

**Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):**

Some one may have the following notion:—“Other men’s wives may be made one’s own by paying money to the husband, and the difficulty regarding ownership being thus removed, the son horn of her would belong to the begetter.”

This is declared to be not possible. Wives of other men cannot be made one s own even by the paying of a thousand gold-coins.

Nor, when she is abandoned by her husband on account of poverty, can the wife belong to the man who receives her.

So, it is clear(from above verse) that it's a crime and not allowed. Now, should women support crimes.

Quoting from [commentary in this verse](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/1/verse/36-37)

> ***Vasiṣhṭh Smṛiti (verse 3.19) under six circumstances it is acceptable to kill; in order to protect themselves from such enemies
> who have: set fire to their property, tried to poison them, conspired
> to murder, loot their wealth, kidnap or dishonor their women, or seize
> their kingdom. .***

Comment: Thanks Sir..Let's leave Sale and Repudiation...What about wilful sending wife to another? Since she is someone else's wife the receiver may not take her(sexually) but can the wife disobey such an order(order to go to another man? Is there any such instance in scripture?)

Comment: @Harsh re read Vasiṣhṭh Smṛiti (verse 3.19)

Comment: Sir you have not understood my question..Suppose there is a perverted husband who orders his wife to go/to sleep with someone else should wife obey such an order or she should disobey such an order..Kindly quote scriptural references..

Comment: @Harsh violence is justified when kidnap or "dishonor  women" . It comes under category of dishonor only even with basic common sense

Comment: I am not saying about violence after dishonour..I am asking if a perverted husband himself asks his wife to sleep with another man then should she obey him or refuse his order according to scriptures?

Comment: @Harsh offcourse rejected ,Yoga-vasistha Verse 2.18.3 The remark of a child is to be accepted, if it is in accordance with reason; but the remark of even Brahma Himself, the creator of the world is to be rejected like a piece of straw if it does not accord with reason.[when word of Almighty God can be rejected do you think word of man should be followed]+also nation laws allow to reject must be given priority [manu 4.175-176]

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir are there anymore such verses which forbid obeying husband's illegal orders..because yoga vasista is a highly extrapolated/intrapolated work

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir are there anymore such verses which forbid obeying husband's illegal orders..because yoga vasista is a highly extrapolated/intrapolated work

Comment: @Harsh in such case current law allows to reject and divorce, manu ch4 :He shall always delight in truthfulness, Law and right conduct, as also in ceanliness (cleanliness?); he shall govern his pupils in accordance with law,—with his speech arms, and belly duly controlled.—He shall, avoid such wealth and pleasures as are opposed to righteousness, as also righteousness if it be conducive to unhappiness, or disapproved by the people.—(176)

Comment: I am not speaking about divorce Sir..I asking any verses which allow wife to disobey Husband's order..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151643/discussion-between-hope-and-harsh).

Comment: Hi sir please respond

Comment: Please respond sir

Comment: @Harsh what you want

Comment: Add your comments here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58355/when-can-one-disobey-superior-persons-orders

Comment: I dont know what comments I should add..