# What are the cases in which wife can disobey her husband?

Tags: mahabharata, smriti

Pranam,
Please provide scriptural references..
Thanks

Comment: [Can wife disobey husband's illegal/adharmic orders?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58349/can-wife-disobey-husbands-illegal-adharmic-orders) Please don't ask duplicate questions.