# Are there any instances in scriptures where wives disobeyed their adharmic husbands?

Tags: puranas, dharma, marriage, smriti

And their anti scriptural instructions?
Kindly mention scriptural references..
Also any references that illegal order of husband should be disobeyed..

Comment: [Can wife disobey husband's illegal/adharmic orders?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58349/can-wife-disobey-husbands-illegal-adharmic-orders) Please don't ask duplicate questions.

Comment: It is not duplicate question...